# How do I build my spring boot project that's trying to reference an external properties file created after deployment to a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, kubernetes, configmap

I'm trying to reference an external properties file to override the default spring properties file.

Dockerfile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:latest
VOLUME /tmp
COPY ./target/basicRestApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app/app.jar"]
```

Deployment

```
volumeMounts:
 - name: config-volume
   mountPath: /app/config

volumes:
  - name: config-volume
    configMap:
     name: test-config-map
```

Configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config-map
  namespace: default
data:
  application.yaml: |-
 key: value .....
```

I've tried to reference the external properties file with a @Configuration class with `@PropertySource("file:$/config/application.yaml")`and attempt to build the program (maven) I get the error `"$/config/application.yaml (No such file or directory)"` and I'm unable to build.

I've also tried adding the command line argument --spring.config.location=file:/app/config/application.yaml in my docker file. This results in another error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load store from '/root/rins_common/rins_service_config/rins-keystore'`

I was expecting to be able to build the application and have the application reference the later-created properties file. But this makes sense  because that file path does not exist till the manifests are applied to the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using @PropertySource you could try to add the command line argument `--spring.config.location=file:/app/config/application.yaml` to the entrypoint, if you want override the default spring properties file.
you can also add this to your K8 Deployment YAML instead of the Dockerfile.

Comment: When adding this to my docker file and deploying, I get the error _Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create key store: Could not load store from '/root/rins_common/rins_service_config/rins-keystore'_

Comment: An environment variable `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` might be easier to set than a command-line option, and would have the same effect in Spring Boot.

Comment: Both solutions are valid and worked. I realized that my issue was resting inside of the properties file as it was trying to reference that _rins-keystore_ file in the directory. Removed that to test and everything worked. Thank you!